# How to evaluate $x^6+x^4+x^3+x^2+1=0$?

Tags: complex-numbers, arithmetic

There is a hint in the question, use the factorization of $x^5+x+1$.

Comment: Do you notice any relation between the hint and the equation?

Comment: I literally added only four characters to your post to make it format pretty.   My point is it would be worth your time to learn the most basic formatting rules for latex.  Rule number one, put dollar signs around your math.

Comment: I would have suggested the factorization of $x^4 + x^2 + 1,$ seems more direct

Comment: sorry i am a new user...

Comment: @WillJagy How does that factorization facilitate?

Comment: Another interesting thing one might note is that the fifth roots of unity other than $1$ are roots of our polynomial.

Comment: @Dr.MV, seems a standard contest trick that $x^a + x^b + 1$ is divisible by $x^2 + x + 1$ if $a \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $b \equiv 2 \pmod 3,$ because of cube roots of unity. Subtract $x^4 + x^2 + 1$ from the original and you have $x^6 + x^3 = x^3 (x^3 + 1) = x^3 (x+1) (x^2 - x+1),$ the final quadratic being the ***other*** factor of $x^4 + x^2 + 1$

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluate"? It looks like the expression is already evaluated in the title of your question; the value is $0.$

Answer (score 5):

How about first multiplying by $(x-1)$ ?

$$(x-1)(x^6+x^4+x^3+x^2+1)= x^7-x^6+x^5 - x^2+x-1= (x^2-x+1)(x^5-1)$$ 
and carry on from there?

Added: Not sure if worth mentioning, but doing the same on $x^5+x+1$ requires an extra little trick:
$$ (x-1)(x^5+x+1)= x^6-x^5 (+x^3 - x^3) +x^2-1=(x^3-x^2+1)(x^3-1)$$

Comment: is it a standard trick to multiply by x-1？

Comment: Don't know. I am not an expert in factorization. Came to my mind when seeing several consecutive terms from a geometric series. One could alternatively multiply by $x^2-1$ to simplify the expression

Answer (score 3):

Divide by $x^3$ and remember that
$$
x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}=\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^3-3\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$
so the equation becomes
$$
\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^3-3\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)
+\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)+1=0
$$
Set $t=x+1/x$ and you get
$$
t^3-2t+1=0
$$
Can you go on? Note that $t=1$ is a solution.

Comment: Wow that is a beautiful method, i was wondering what is the motivation behind these step...

Comment: @Rikka The motivation is that if $a$ is a solution of the equation, also $1/a$ is: just substitute and clear the denominator; it's a quite old trick for reducing the degree of this kind of equations. We basically put together two roots, reducing the sextic to a cubic.

Answer (score 2):

I missed something. Standard contest trick. The exponents used are 
$$ 1,4,3,2,0 \pmod 5  $$
while all coefficients are $1.$

That means that the nontrivial fifth roots of unity are roots and the polynomial must be divisible by $$ x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 $$

Comment: Nice observation!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better hint:

$$x^6+x^4+x^3+x^2+1=(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$